# MySQL SET inserts only the first item in a list

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using NodeJs msyql,

```
var telemetryItemList = [
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '1', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '2', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '3', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '4', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '5', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue }
];

pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) {
        throw new Error('Could not get DB connection');
    }
    conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${Config.tableName} SET ?`, telemetryItemList, (err, res) => {
    .
    .
    .
```

The code above inserts only the first row of the list, why is that?

**UPDATE**

Following good answers I received here, I believe it is best to flush the entire object to the database and not to create a query on each row

Something like:

```
var telemetryItemList2 = [
    ['created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '1', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue],
    ['created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '2', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue],
    ['created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '3', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue],
    ['created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '4', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue],
    ['created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '5', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue],
];
```

but how do I struct the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
var telemetryItemList = [
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '1', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '2', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '3', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '4', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
    { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '5', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue }
];

pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) {
        throw new Error('Could not get DB connection');
    }
    conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${Config.tableName} SET ?`, [telemetryItemList], (err, res) => {
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: please pass using array may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
var telemetryItemList = [
  { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '1', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
  { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '2', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
  { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '3', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
  { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '4', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue },
  { 'created_at': createdAt, 'device_type': deviceType + '5', 'device_serial': deviceSerial , 'metric_name': metricName, 'metric_value': metricValue }
];
```

Try iterating over `telemetryItemList`:

```
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
  if(err) {
      throw new Error('Could not get DB connection');
  }
  telemetryItemList.forEach(row => {
    conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${Config.tableName} SET ?`, row, (err, res) => {
      //
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: does the code mean that you open a new connection each time you iterate? if yes, what do you offer? perhaps I should model the telemteryItemList other way

Comment: No, only one connection is opened at `pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {/*...*/});`

Comment: Then, on each iteration of the array it is performed a query insert: `conn.query('INSERT INTO ${Config.tableName} SET ?', row, (err, res) => {});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INSERT ... VALUES`, (`INSERT ... SET` has no bulk support), and also set `telemetryItemList` as array :

```
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) {
        throw new Error('Could not get DB connection');
    }
    conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${Config.tableName} (created_at, device_type, device_serial, metric_name, metric_value) VALUES ?`, [telemetryItemList.map(tel_arr => [tel_arr.created_at, tel_arr.device_type, tel_arr.device_serial, tel_arr.metric_name, tel_arr.metric_value])], (err, res) => {
    .
    .
    .
```

Reference :
[Bulk inserting array of objects](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/814)